# Neo4j Desktop Install Error when downloading Java 8 on Mac

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I've downloaded Neo4j desktop on my computer and as part of the install process, it installs Java 8. Right now it throws the following error after the download is completed:

> Initialization error: Error: MD5 sum of the downloaded file did not match the expected value. Please try again!

Can't seem to find anything online / anyone else with this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDtzM.png) of the error that the installation is throwing.

Comment: Did you click the "Retry" button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the download script, I've raised a ticket

here is a workaround, tested

Download http://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/zulu8.21.0.1-jdk8.0.131-macosx_x64.tar.gz

Copy the compressed file to:
 /Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/distributions

Relaunch Neo4j Desktop

Should complete the install.

Comment: I tried the above and still got the errors:

$ pwd
/Users/[me]/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/distributions

$ ls
java      neo4j      zulu8.21.0.1-jdk8.0.131-macosx_x64.tar.gz

$ md5 zulu8.21.0.1-jdk8.0.131-macosx_x64.tar.gz 
MD5 (zulu8.21.0.1-jdk8.0.131-macosx_x64.tar.gz) = 455a4ab570b9486ec294c423275399df

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael. I've done as you said, but I'm still running into the same error.

Comment: Worked for me! Needed to paste in the java directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error

> Initialization error: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, ..etc

I tried to installed Neo4J desktop in windows 7 64bit OS.

Uninstalling Node.js worked for me.